# Can not successfully receive a message object from a 'window.postMessage' in AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, postmessage

Pretty new to AngularJS - try not to laugh. Having trouble understanding how to properly receive a `window.postMessage` object in an AngularJS app.

There is an `iframe` embedded in the AngularJS app page originating from a non-AngularJS app which calls `window.postMessage` on the parent window in an attempt to send a message object to the AngularJS application.

I do receive the `postMessage` event successfully, but the `event.data` is not the message I sent as it is in other non-Angular apps - it looks like something the AngularJS framework created.

Why do I get this result? Is there a proper AngularJS way to successfully receive the message object I'm sending from the other window?

`window.addEventListener("message", function(e) { //do stuff here }, false);`

I want `e.data` to be the message I sent from the embedded window.

Comment: This should be able to be accomplished by injecting `$window` and placing the event listener on that rather than the vanilla JS window object. Possible duplicate -- [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987676/window-postmessage-between-iframe-and-its-parent-with-angular-does-anyone-have)

Comment: Please show the code used to invoke `window.postMessage` and the event object that gets received. "It looks like something the Angular framework created" is too vague to understand what is happening.

Comment: AAAAARRRRG! Thank you charliebeckwith and georgeawg for your interest in my problem. I managed to solve it myself though. It turns out that I am a moron and forgot I had 'AngularJS Batarang' extension installed and active in Chrome and totally forgot about it. It was modifying message event data to include info to help debugging - Signed Clueless and Embarrassed.